# Add multiple exclusions to this javascript

Tags: javascript

Someone recently gave me this code to fix my radio button issue, It works perfectly but how can i exclude more groups of radio buttons?

I also want to exclude "lunch_fruitjuice" as well as "lunch_desserts"

```
$(function(){
    // cache the selector for all target radio buttons for later use
    var targetRadioButtons = $("input:radio").not("input:radio[name=lunch_desserts]");

    targetRadioButtons.change(function(){
        var currentGroupName = $(this).prop("name");       

        // remove selected state from other items
        targetRadioButtons.not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
})
```

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend adding a common class to all radio buttons which you would like to select and then just use the class selector: `$(".select-me")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var targetRadioButtons = $("input:radio").not("input:radio[name=lunch_desserts]").not("input:radio[name=lunch_fruitjuice]");
```

Comment: While this might work your code will get really ugly really fast. What happens with you want to add another 5 excluded elements?

Comment: Yeah i just realised that, i just posted a reply to yours. Is there a way to reverse it?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit ugly, but it should work:

```
$("input:radio").not("input:radio[name=lunch_desserts]").not("input:radio[name=lunch_fruitjuice]").not(...)
```

All you have to do is chain the `not()` commands one after the other excluding all the elements you want.

A better approach would be to give all of your radio inputs that you *do* want to handle a similar class (for example `use_these_ones`). That way the line will be as simple as this:

```
var targetRadioButtons = $("input.use_these_ones")
```

Comment: I've just realised i have more radio buttons that need including rather than excluding, Do you know if theres a way to reverse the script i posted so i only write the buttons that i want to include ?

Comment: I recommend using the class method that I suggested... Simply add the same class to all the elements you want to ignore and then use `.not()` to exclude them : `var targetRadioButtons = $("input:radio").not(".ignore_me_class");`

Comment: So the radio button would be like: <input class="ignore_me_class" type="radio" name="lunch_dinner">

Comment: @Exoon - yes! exactly!

Comment: I cant get it working, Im using PHP to generate the radio buttons from a database, i added a row called "ignore_class" and made it so when its set to 1 it will echo class="ignore_me" then added var targetRadioButtons = $("input:radio").not(".ignore_me"); at the top but it isnt working, Any ideas?

Comment: oh sorry i was thinking the other way around, when i changed the 1 to a 0 it worked great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude certain radio buttons from your selection, you should probably add a class to the radio buttons you wish to exclude. Like this:

HTML

```
<div><input type="radio" name="lunch_desserts" class="exclude" value="Jello"/> Jello</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="lunch_desserts" value="Pudding"/> Pudding</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="lunch_desserts" class="exclude" value="Candy"/> Candy</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="lunch_fruitjuice" value="Apple Juice"/> Apple Juice</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="lunch_fruitjuice" class="exclude" value="Orange Juice"/> Orange Juice</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="lunch_fruitjuice" value="Guava Juice"/> Guava Juice</div>
```

JavaScript

```
// Select radio buttons that do not have the exclude class
var targetRadioButtons = $("input:radio:not(.exclude)");

// Test it by disabling just the targetRadioButtons
targetRadioButtons.attr("disabled", true);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J2DXF/

Answer (score 0):

```
var exclude = ['lunch_fruitjuice', 'lunch_desserts'];
var targetRadioButtons = $("input:radio");
for (var i = 0; i < exclude .length; i++)
    targetRadioButtons = targetRadioButtons.not("input:radio[name="+exclude[i]+"]");
```

Comment: With each iteration you are overriding the `targetRadioButtons` variable. Perhaps you meant to create an array of all the elements? Even if you did - you are negating the need for selectors with this sort of loop logic.

Comment: @Lix, you're wrong. .not() returns JQuery object. This code is right exactly the same reason the chaineable style works. http://jsfiddle.net/Uu2Qs/

Comment: Oh... sorry - yes, you're right... I missed that it was `targetRadioButtons.not(...)`. I still feel that the loop is unnecessary though... (Doing a fake edit to revert my vote.)